# 403 - Forbidden: error when calling view file in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, yii

So, I am running into a 403 forbidden error in a JavaScript call I am making in Yii. I am using XAMPP and I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. This is my first time using JavaScript/jQuery in Yii - so I don't know if there is something obvious that I should change.
A lot of posts have talked about using .htaccess - but I'm not entirely sure how that works, or where I would put that file.

Here is the call in my view

```
<script> 
function getBalance(){
    $.get("protected/views/account/balance.php", "", function(data){

        alert(data);
    });
}
getBalance();
</script>
```

And the page balance.php simply has the number 7000 (to test with). However, it is denied with 403 (Forbidden). Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: What are the file permissions for the php file and its parent directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Yii, you cannot call the PHP files directly like that. You have to set up an action in the controller like this:

*protected/controllers/CustomController.php*

```
<?php
class CustomController extends Controller {

    public function balanceAction() {

        // Return a string
        echo "7000";

        // or, render a view file.
        // This example will render protected/views/custom/index.php
        $this->render('index');
    }
```

then the access control filter and rules in the controller has to be set to allow that new action you just created,

```
<?php
class CustomController extends Controller {

    public function filters() {
        return array(
            'accessControl',
        );
    }
    public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                // add the action name in lowercase in this array
                //  (without the word 'action')
                'actions' => array('balance'), 
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            // deny all other actions
            array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

and then in your ajax call or hyperlinks, you will need to call the file using a URL that should look like "controllerName/actionName", in the example above, I would be using "**custom/balance**"

```
    $.get("custom/balance", function(){  });
```

Comment: Samuel, so this was an incredible answer (which is why I marked it correct - thank you again)
$.get("custom/balance") did not work however. I needed to change this piece of code to 
$.get("index.php?r=account/balance", function(data) {}) 

Is this the best way to go about doing it though? it feels like this syntax could be done much better.